# Objective-C creating a dynamic bidimensional array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to create a class that can manage bidimensional array.
I used the same algorithm in C without objects (obviously) and it works fine.
The problem is that when i try to modify a variable of my object it doesn't modify it in the main program, and it is absurd!

### NSMatrice.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct ogmat
{
    float value;
    int row, col;
    struct ogmat *next;
};

typedef struct ogmat Tmat;
typedef Tmat* TpTmat;

@interface NSMatrice : NSObject{
    TpTmat m;
}
- (void)    crea;       //inizializza la matrice
- (int)     destroy;    //la distrugge
- (BOOL)    exisistsatxy :(int) x :(int) y;
- (void)    setvalueatxy :(float) value :(int) x :(int) y;
- (float)   getvalueatxy :(int) x :(int) y;

@end
```

### NSMatrice.c

```
#import "NSMatrice.h"
@implementation NSMatrice
- (void)    crea{       //inizializza la matrice
    m=NULL;
}
- (int)     destroy{    //la distrugge
    while (m!=NULL){
        TpTmat pa;
        pa=m->next;
        free(m);
        m=NULL;
        m=pa;
    }
    return 1;
}
- (BOOL)    exisistsatxy :(int) x :(int) y{
    while (m!=NULL&&(!(m->col==y&&m->row==x))){
        m=m->next;
    }
    if (m==NULL) return FALSE;
    else return TRUE;
}
- (void)    setvalueatxy :(float) value :(int) x :(int) y{
    Tmat *pa;
    if (!([self exisistsatxy:x:y])){//nuova testa modifico pa
        pa=malloc(sizeof(Tmat));
        pa->col=y;
        pa->row=x;
        pa->value=value;
        pa->next=m;
        m=pa;
    }else{
        pa=m;
        while (pa!=NULL&&(!(pa->col==y&&pa->row==x))){//stessa testa
            pa=pa->next;
        }
        if (pa!=NULL){
            pa->value=value;
        }
    }
}
- (float)   getvalueatxy :(int) x :(int) y{
    Tmat *pa;
    pa=m;
    while (pa!=NULL&&(!(pa->col==y&&pa->row==x))){
        pa=pa->next;
    }
    if (pa!=NULL){
        return pa->value;
    }
    else return 0;
}
@end
```

### obj_mat.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSMatrice.h"
#import <time.h>

int main () {
    NSMatrice *m;
    int i,j;
    m=[NSMatrice alloc];
    [m crea];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
            [m setvalueatxy:rand()%20 :i :j];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
            printf("%.2f\t",[m getvalueatxy:i :j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not going to get much response if people have to download an unknown zip. Just edit your answer and paste the code in. Then select it and click on the little **{}** button over the editor. Poof, readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect its got something to do with your `exisistsatxy` method - that changes the link in the list that `m` addresses, rather than making a copy of the pointer and using that to traverse - which is what you do in `setvalueatxy` method.